# Apartir de 2 tablas insertar la informacion de ciertos campos en otra tabla nueva

Tags: postgresql

mi tabla nueva donde quiero insertar los datos tiene estas columnas:

```
gid,cvegeo,nom_ent,nom_mun,nom_loc,longitud,latitud,altitud,geom
```

las otras 2 tablas tienen 200 columnas, entre las columnas de estas se llaman igual que la tabla nueva el nombre de mis tablas son `loc_urb_spheric` y `loc_rur_spheric`. Mi tabla nueva tiene el mismo tipo de dato de las columnas que quiero sacar

esta es mi consulta la cual no funciona:

```
INSERT INTO locaciones gid,cvegeo,nom_ent,nom_mun,nom_loc,longitud,latitud,altitud,geom FROM ( SELECT a.gid,a.cvegeo,a.nom_ent,a.nom_mun,a.nom_loc,
a.longitud,a.latitud,a.altitud,a.geom from loc_rur_spheric a UNION SELECT b.gid,b.cvegeo,b.nom_ent,b.nom_mun,b.nom_loc,
b.longitud,b.latitud,b.altitud,b.geom from loc_urb_spheric b );
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Qué es intentado hasta a ahora?

Comment: ahi está mi consulta la cual no funciona, alguna idea?

Comment: Dices que no funciona, pero no dices de qué manera no funciona. ¿Recibes algún error? ¿Qué sucede?

Comment: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «gid»
LINE 1: INSERT INTO locaciones gid,cvegeo,nom_ent,nom_mun,nom_loc,lo...
                               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «gid»
SQL state: 42601
Character: 24

Comment: Para que quieres insertar los datos de 2 tablas en una nueva?

Comment: Has siquiera mirado la documentacion del INSERT INTO para verificar la sintaxis? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como la documentación de [INSERT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-insert.html) indica, la sintaxis correcta es

```
  INSERT INTO <tabla> (<columnas>)
      <query>
```

Es decir:

```
  INSERT INTO locaciones (gid, cvegeo, ... )
  SELECT a.gid,a.cvegeo,a.nom_ent,a.nom_mun,a.nom_loc,
              a.longitud,a.latitud,a.altitud,a.geom 
           FROM loc_rur_spheric a 
  UNION         
  SELECT  b.gid,b.cvegeo,b.nom_ent,b.nom_mun,b.nom_loc,
            b.longitud,b.latitud,b.altitud,b.geom 
  FROM loc_urb_spheric b
```

Comment: Gracias eso fue lo que me funcionó te agradesco mucho